# Dynamic Assign in BPEL 2.0

Tags: xpath, bpel

Is it possible to dynamically generate an assign xpath from a variable and an XPath string.

ie.

```
<assign name="dynamicAssign">
    <copy>
        <from>$VariablePayload/$xpath_into_variable_payload</from>
        <to>...</to>
     </copy>
</assign>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to feed in an XPath expression from a variable. What you could do instead is to rewrite your XPath in order to select elements whose names come from other variables. This however is still a quite static approach. To achieve this, you can use an XPath predicate together with the name() or local-name() function.

e.g.:

```
<assign name="dynamicAssign">
   <copy>
       <from>$VariablePayload/*[local-name() = $firstElementName]</from>
       <to>...</to>
    </copy>
 </assign>
```

Comment: $VariablePayload//*[local-name() = $firstElementName] - adding the second slash helps when the element is located a number of steps down.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be truly dynamic you'd have to write an eval function. This would be platform and language specific as I'm sure each platform has their own API for defining custom xpath functions.